# query string parameter without value, only key

Tags: asp.net, query-string

i have question about query string in asp.net:

standart query string with query string parameter is `"www.mysity.url?key1=value1&key2=value2"`, but i need only check has query string key or not...yes, one of the correct decisions: `www.mysite.url?reset=true`, but this excess syntax for me.

in markup i use something like `"<a href='UrlHelper.GetResetUrl()'>Reset</a>"`, this method return `"www.mysity.url?reset"`, but in user side markup i have "Reset"

Comment: You know that you can simple check your url if contains the "?reset" and that's all.

Answer (score 6):

If you do not specify the name for a parameter it is taken as `null`.

Its value would be `reset`

So you would have to check it as follows:

```
if(Request.QueryString[null]=="reset")
{
    //Take some reset action
}
```

Comment: this answer was useful for me, as the values are dynamic

Answer (score 1):

a Quick and dirty solution is:

```
if(Request.Url.Query.Contains("?reset"))
{
    // ok we have a reset
}
```

Assuming that you have a standard reset call ask as: `www.mysity.url?reset` and the reset url not have other parameters. If you have you can simple check for the `reset` keyword.

This code `HttpContext.Current.Request["reset"]` is always return null, so the next best thing if you like to make it hard, is to manual analyze your keys after the url.

Answer (score 0):

All code that handles querystring parameters should be case insensitive. Browsers (or parts of internet infrastructure?) may convert the case.

One way to check if reset parameter is present in querystring:

```
bool reset = Request.Url.Query.IndexOf("reset", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) > -1;
```